# How to populate JComboBox using a method that accepts string as combobox name

Tags: java, swing

I would like to populate multiple `JComboBox` in a GUI. So I would like to use a method that accepts each `JComboBox` name as an argument. Is this possible?

```
cmbCustomers.addItem("customer name");
```

In the code above I would like to replace cmbCustomers with any possible string that is passed to the populate method.

I have tried to pass a string argument from a populate method to replace the cmbCustomers comboboxname dynamically, but it really doesn't seem possible.

I'm making a GUI that populates `JTables` with data from a database. Selecting a row in a particular `JTable` populates a set of `JComboBoxes` with the selected row's data. From here the data can be changed using the `JComboBoxes`and saved back to the database. Because of the multiple `JComboBoxes`I'd like to avoid duplicating so much code.

Comment: Can you post your full code

Comment: Your question in essence is "how can I associate some object with a String?". One answer is to use a `HashMap<String, JComboBox>` that will associate pairs of Strings with JComboBoxes. Having said this, your question has an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) smell to it where you ask how to solve a specific code problem when the best solution is to use a completely different approach. Better that you tell us the overall problem that you're trying to solve rather than how you're currently trying to solve it.

Comment: You can refer this link documents http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddItemstoJComboBox.htm

Comment: @Akash: that link doesn't address the main question: that of using multiple JComboBoxes and getting a JComboBox reference based on a String.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, Thanks for your insights. I'm making a GUI that populates JTables with data from a database.  Selecting a row in a particular JTable populates a set of comboboxes with the selected row's data.  From here the data can be changed using the comboboxes and saved back to the database.  Because of the multiple comboboxes I'd like to avoid duplicating so much code.

Comment: Thank you for that information. The information that you've given above is key information and should be part of your original question, and not buried down inside of comments given its importance. You also should post relevant code, preferably as a [mcve], to give us more specific information about your program structure, as this will allow the answers to be more specific and helpful, not just to you, but also to future visitors to this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Java variable names are only available at compile time. You cannot use a String value as a variable name at run time<sup>1</sup>. Instead, you should use general Object Oriented principles to solve your problem. In this case, you can write a method which accepts a JComboBox parameter:

```
private void populateComboBox(JComboBox comboBox) {
    comboBox.addItem("customer name");
    // ... do anything else you wish with the comboBox
}
```

Now you can call this method with any JComboBox. Note that the name of the parameter passed to the method **does not matter**. It can be anything you want. For example:

```
JComboBox cmbCustomers = new JComboBox();
populateComboBox(cmbCustomers);
```

or

```
JComboBox cmbOtherCustomers= new JComboBox();
populateComboBox(cmbOtherCustomers);
```

I strongly suggest that you learn as much as you can about methods and reference variables. These concepts are critical to Java programming and will help you understand my suggestion above as well as help you use them to solve similar problems in the future.

<sup>1 Technically, you can use the Reflection API to do this. Reflection is intended for code introspection in code tools, not for standard day-to-day programming. You should definitely not use it to solve common problems such as the one asked about here.</sup>

Comment: Decent answer for what so far is an incomplete question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to dynamically create the code name for anything? It is extremely rare that there would be any reason to do so. What difference does it make if your call the combobox "box1" or "mybox" ? How will you write the code to manipulate the content of the combobox if you do not know the variable name of the combobox until run-time?

That said, there is a setName() and a getName() method for all Components, and you can certainly modify that internal name at any time. Then you can do things like:

```
  if ( box1.getName().equals(something) ) {
    fillCustomers( box1, customers );
  } else if ( box2.getName().equals( something ) {
    fdillCustomers( box2, customers );
  }
```

Admittedly, this is a rather poor design to use to modify what types of things are in a particular combobox, but it can be done.