# How to populate multiple JTables using a method where there are variable columns

Tags: java, swing

I would like to populate more than one JTable using the code below.  The amount of columns in the 2D array can be variable. So I would like to use a method that accepts an integer to indicate the number of columns to add in the following line:

```
tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{arr[i][0], arr[i][1]});
```

I'm trying to figure a way to add (for each new JTable) a specified number of arr[i][0], arr[i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653448/how-to-populate-jcombobox-using-a-method-that-accepts-string-as-combobox-name?noredirect=1#comment78266114_45653448), to a table determined by a method argument.

```
DefaultTableModel tableModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[]{arr[i][0], arr[i][1]});
}
```

Is this possible?

This is linked in a way to my previous question: [How to populate a JComboBox using a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653448/how-to-populate-jcombobox-using-a-method-that-accepts-string-as-combobox-name?noredirect=1#comment78266114_45653448)

Comment: Again, posting a more complete small program, a [mcve] would help greatly in improving our understanding of your code and your problem. Also please have a look at Jon Skeet's ["Stack Overflow question checklist"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) which can be useful when you want to write good question.

Comment: The key to your problem is in creating a flexible TableModel. Perhaps you want to use a factory method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order for data to be displayed in a `JTable`, you must have a column defined in the `TableColumnModel` of the table.

So you need to define your `DefaultTableModel` with the maximum number of columns that is possible.

Then you just use the `addRow(...)` method. `The DefaultTableModel` will automatically pad the row with null values up to the maximum number of columns.